# Do Rails' model hooks wait until database transactions are completed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with an `after_save` and `after_commit` hook. The `after_save` hook stores some information in the database which are needed by the `after_commit` hook.

Is it safe to assume that all database transaction are finished before the `after_commit` hook fires?

Here's a little example to illustrate the problem:

```rb
class TicketComment < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :extract_mentions
  after_commit :notify

  def extract_mentions
    current_mentions = mentions.map(&:user).map(&:username)
    new_mentions = description.scan(/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-ZÀ-ž0-9_-]))@([a-zA-ZÀ-ž]+[a-zA-ZÀ-ž0-9_]+)/).flatten

    mentions_to_add = new_mentions - current_mentions
    mentions_to_remove = current_mentions - new_mentions

    users_to_add = User.select(:id).where("username IN (?)", mentions_to_add.flatten).map(&:id)
    users_to_remove = User.select(:id).where("username IN (?)", mentions_to_remove.flatten).map(&:id)

    users_to_add&.each do |id_to_add|
      mentions.create(user_id: id_to_add)
    end

    mentions.where(user_id: users_to_remove).destroy_all
  end

  def notify
    user_ids = ticket.participants.pluck(:id) - [Current.user.id]
    TicketCommentMailer.comment_added(id, user_ids).deliver_later
  end
end
```

Please mind that this example is simplified. The `extract_mentions`-part is a model concern which is used across multiple models, so I can't run the `notify` code inside the `extract_mentions`-hook.

Comment: ``after_commit`` hooks definitely run after the last (parent) transaction commits, while ``after_save`` runs directly at persistence time. The ``.create`` calls in your callbacks are wrapped under the transaction of the original ``.save``, so everything commits before ``.notify`` runs. The docs warn that updating model attributes inside a hook leads to unpredictable state behaviour, but I don't know if that applies to creating whole new objects like you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment with some reference, yes you can assume that all database transactions have finished before your `#after_commit` callback runs. Here is a comment in `active_record/transaction.rb` ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb)):

> #after_commit callbacks are called on every record saved or destroyed within a
> transaction immediately after the transaction is committed. #after_rollback callbacks
> are called on every record saved or destroyed within a transaction immediately after the
> transaction or savepoint is rolled back.
>
> These callbacks are useful for interacting with other systems since you will be guaranteed
> that the callback is only executed when the database is in a permanent state.

The transaction code is a bit hairy, since it handles nested transactions, savepoints, etc. Ultimately, though, in `TransactionManager.commit_transaction` ([active_record/connect_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb#L215)), the manager does indeed execute the database-specific commit action before running `#after_commit` callbacks on all unique record IDs association with a parent transaction.

```rb
def commit_transaction
  @connection.lock.synchronize do
    ...
    transaction.commit  # executes database-specific commit action
    transaction.commit_records # executes after_commit callbacks
  end
end
```

All save and destroy operations, including their persistence callbacks, are implicitly wrapped in a transaction block. Per another comment in the Rails `active_record/transaction.rb`:

> #transaction calls can be nested. By default, this makes all database
> statements in the nested transaction block become part of the parent
> transaction.

So, database statements generated by the `#create` and `#destroy_all` in your `#after_save` callback are committed at the same time with the original parent transaction, and can be depended on in the `#after_commit` callback. A simplified example to illustrate:

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :do_stuff
  after_commit :check

  def do_stuff
    Bar.create!(name: 'bar')
  end

  def check
    Rails.logger.info "Bar count: #{Bar.count}"
    Rails.logger.info "name: #{Bar.first.name}"
  end
end
```

Output log:

```
> Foo.create!(name: "Jerry")
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Foo Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "foos" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Jerry"], ["created_at", "2020-09-16 01:49:57.480367"], ["updated_at", "2020-09-16 01:49:57.480367"]]
  Bar Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "bars" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "bar"], ["created_at", "2020-09-16 01:49:57.485953"], ["updated_at", "2020-09-16 01:49:57.485953"]]
 (2.3ms)  commit transaction
 (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bars"
Bar count: 1
  Bar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" ORDER BY "bars"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
bar
```

Note that of course any `#after_commit` callbacks will be invoked for any model that is created, updated, or destroyed within the transaction. So, if `Bar` also defines `#after_commit` callbacks, those get run too.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much :)